# Getting the contents from a window.open()'ed window after redirect

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I have a web application that runs in Chrome with Same-Origin Policy disabled (i.e., `--disable-web-security`). I use `window.open()` to create a new window that loads a URI that sometimes redirects. If no redirect occurs, I can read the contents of the document hosted inside the window using the `document` property when the `onload` event fires. Unfortunately, in cases where a redirect does occur, it seems that `onload` never fires, and the window object returned from `window.open()` is no longer useful.

Here's the code, to give you an idea of what's going on:

```
var win = window.open('http://somewhere');
win.onload = function() {
  doStuffWith(win.document.body);
  win.close();
};
```

Is there any way that I can hold on to a valid `window` handle even when a redirect occurs immediately after the new window is opened?

---

Per @CBroe's suggestion I extended my code to see if I can get at the contents of the window if I wait a little while. After the code above, I appended:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(win.location);
  doStuffWith(win.document.body);
}, 5000);
```

The `location` is reported as `swappedout://` (huh!?) and the document's body is empty.

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the page the window redirects to?

Comment: No, that's the thing. I have absolutely no control over what's loaded into the new window.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't same-origin policy get determined by the server rather than the client?

Comment: The server dictates the policy; the client enforces it. I told my client not to.

Comment: @sg.cc: Same Origin Policy is enforced client-side, simply based on whether protocol, host name and port match or not. Maybe you’re confusing it with CORS here? (In that, the remote server has a say in the matter.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, that's what I was thinking of.

Comment: @CBroe your comment made it clear that I am confusing it with CORS too... :-)

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what _“and the window object returned from window.open() is no longer useful”_ means? Does the reference get lost altogether, do you get errors when trying to access it? If the `load` event doesn’t fire, can you get to the content if you wait a while using a timeout?

Comment: @CBroe I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the relocation is not exactly after lets say an on click event pop-up blocker provided by most browsers blocks the request, on success of some function you want, open a modal with a button and have the relocate on click of the new button. Its the only way. Not great but it will do the trick.

This also applies to the on load.

Comment: I disabled the pop-up blocker, so it doesn't interfere. Normally the window loads just fine, except for cases involving redirects.